# Which xsl-fo elements can be the destination of a fo:basic-link with internal-destination?

Tags: pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop, docbook

I have a document in docbook format. I used to generate HTML from this. Now I tried to generate xsl-fo and then use Apache fop to build a pdf. However fop emitted several warnings about missing link destinations and they don't work in the produced pdf. These links works fine with HTML output. I can see that the missing id:s are actually present in the xsl-fo. It seems like some links works, for example those with a docbook section element as destination. However those which points to a docbook table row element doesn't work.

Is this a docbook bug? Or are there limitations in xsl-fo on which elements might be link destinations? A fop bug? Or actually a limitation in the pdf format itself?

Comment: Can you post the resulting FO snippet?

Comment: I would assume that (per the specification) that the destination must be in the area tree -- "Specifies the destination flow object within the formatting object tree." Some objects may not result in any object in the area tree and hence, no ID would be available to link to.

Answer (score 0):

Embarrasing that I didn't found it before. It's a known fop bug, fop-2110.